# Hide elements in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of such format:

```
var arr = [{ source: "Hello", target: "Bonjour" },
           { source: "Good morning" },
           { source: "Bye" },
           { source: "Good night" }];
```

I represent it in the html in the followin way:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchSource">

<div ng-repeat="element in arr | filter: {source: searchSource} track by $index>
    <strong>{{element.source}}</strong>
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="element.target">
    <br>
</div>
```

I need to make a button, which will hide elements with `target` property. I made it with the help of filter first, then tried with ng-hide. It works, it hides elements with `target` but when I start to write something into another `<input>` fileds they are hidden instantly, and I don't need this behavior.

I need to hide elements only on button press and not while inputting the text. Behavior should be the following: 
1) Pressed button, to hide elements with `target`. It hides first element of `arr` because it has `target`. So now there are 3 elements on the screen. 
2) Input some text into second element and it shouldn't be hidden. 
3) Press the button and all elements are shown. 
4) Press the button again and now 1st and 2nd elements are hidden, because they have `target`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do so, you have hide the element only at one moment. Not an hide as watchers. This is how I did it. One button hide which will check all your element and hide the one needed. One we will open all your element. While you don't click on hide button again, your item won't be hide.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchSource">
          <button ng-click="hideElement()">Hide</button>
          <button ng-click="isHide = false;">Open</button>
    <div ng-repeat="element in arr | filter: {source: searchSource} track by $index">
        <div ng-hide="element.isHide && isHide">
            <strong>{{element.source}}</strong>
            <br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="element.target"> 
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And then you will have a var to hide or not all element. Plus the function which is suppose to hide some specific element.

```
$scope.isHide = false;

$scope.hideElement = function(){
  $scope.isHide = true;
  for(i = 0; i <$scope.arr.length ; i++){
    if($scope.arr[i].target){
        $scope.arr[i].isHide = true;  
    }
}
```

This function is manually run so it won't be launch when you will change the value of your `element.target`

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5pu7o1tx/)

Comment: Nice answer.  This seems what the OP is looking for!

Comment: Thanks, it seems the best solution for now.